# Sophos on-access scan ignoring uploaded files

Tags: wordpress, centos, antivirus

I'm running Sophos AV on a Centos 7 server.

The on-access scanner seems to be working for files created manually, but not those created via upload.

I am using the EICAR test string `X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*` to trigger the scanner.

- Create a file on the server - SophosAV detects and quarantines it.
- Upload the file through the Wordpress media menu the file is uploaded to `/var/www/assets/uploads/2020/03/eicar.jpg` - The file is NOT detected.
- Run `/opt/sophos-av/savscan /var/www/assets/uploads/2020/03` - the uploaded file IS detected
- Run `cat /var/www/assets/uploads/2020/03/eicar.jpg > /var/www/assets/uploads/2020/03/eicar2.jpg` - The newly created file IS detected, the original one is ignored.
- The uploaded file can be accessed + downloaded via the browser without issue from Sophos.

I'm limiting the types of files that can be uploaded via the backend, but I want to have Sophos scanning them as well for increased security.

Am I doing something wrong, or misunderstanding something fundamental about how Sophos on-demand works?

**EDIT**

Following Douglas Leeder's answer below I have removed `-open` from `TalpaOperations`, which should enable on-access scanning when a file is read, as well as written to.

I have also taken Wordpress out of the equation, and just made a simple PHP upload script which takes a file from `$_POST` and runs

```
rename($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'var/www/uploads'.$_FILES['file']['name']);`
```

to move the uploaded file.

The upload itself runs fine, but now I cannot `cat` the uploaded file (even as root)

```
$ cat eicar 
cat: eicar: Operation not permitted

// Sophos log
<log>
    <category>log.threat</category>
    <level>ERROR</level>
    <domain>savscand</domain>
    <msg>NOTIFY-THREAT-INFECTED-NO-ACCESSED-PATH</msg>
    <time>1583232176</time>
    <arg>/var/www/uploads/eicar</arg>
    <arg>EICAR-AV-Test</arg>
    <arg>OPERATION_OPEN</arg>

</log>
```

I CAN however still open / download the file via the browser.

It's like the HTTPD process is somehow able to get read / write access to the file system in a way that bypasses Sophos / Talpa.

```
$ sudo  /opt/sophos-av/bin/savscan -v

SAVScan virus detection utility
Copyright (c) 1989-2020 Sophos Limited. All rights reserved.

System time 12:09:37, System date 02 March 2020

Product version           : 5.63.0
Engine version            : 3.77.1
Virus data version        : 5.72
User interface version    : 2.03.077
Platform                  : Linux/AMD64
Released                  : 04 February 2020
Total viruses (with IDEs) : 46940998

Information on additional data files:

Data file name            : /opt/sophos-av/lib/sav/spy-ayt.ide
Data file type            : IDE
Data file date            : 07 January 2020, 14:48:22
Data file status          : Loaded

... Lots more data files ...
```

```
# savd.cfg #
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SophosAntiVirus xmlns="savd.xsd">
  <Sophos>
    <OnAccess>
      <EnableOnStart>true</EnableOnStart>
      <Quarantine>false</Quarantine>
      <TakeActionOnClose>false</TakeActionOnClose>
      <RestrictProcessExclusions>false</RestrictProcessExclusions>
      <OnEnable>
        <StartupTimeoutMs>60000</StartupTimeoutMs>
        <Scan/>
        <NoScan/>
      </OnEnable>
      <OnDisable>
        <StopTimeoutMs>30000</StopTimeoutMs>
        <ScanTimeoutMs>10000</ScanTimeoutMs>
        <Scan/>
        <NoScan/>
      </OnDisable>
      <Scanner>
        <HookModule>talpa_vfshook</HookModule>
        <Processes>2</Processes>
        <ThreadsPerProcess>5</ThreadsPerProcess>
        <AdaptiveThreading>true</AdaptiveThreading>
        <MaximumThreads>5</MaximumThreads>
        <MissingHeartbeatDurationSec>60</MissingHeartbeatDurationSec>
        <AutomaticAction/>
        <DenyOnDetectionError>false</DenyOnDetectionError>
        <DenyOnOperatingSystemError>true</DenyOnOperatingSystemError>
        <DenyOnCorruptFile>false</DenyOnCorruptFile>
        <AllowIfEncrypted>false</AllowIfEncrypted>
        <AllowIfPartVolume>false</AllowIfPartVolume>
        <AllowIfNotSupported>false</AllowIfNotSupported>
        <AllowCorruptInCleanArchive>true</AllowCorruptInCleanArchive>
        <TalpaDevicePath>/dev/sophos-vc</TalpaDevicePath>
        <TalpaVettingTimeoutMs>100</TalpaVettingTimeoutMs>
        <TalpaVettingGroup>0</TalpaVettingGroup>
        <FileCacheSizeBytes>4096</FileCacheSizeBytes>
        <UseExtendedRegex>true</UseExtendedRegex>
        <GracePeriods>
          <StopTimeoutMs>20000</StopTimeoutMs>
          <KillTimeoutMs>2000</KillTimeoutMs>
        </GracePeriods>
        <RespawnThrottling>
          <Limit>5</Limit>
          <Max>10</Max>
          <PeriodDurationMs>20000</PeriodDurationMs>
        </RespawnThrottling>
        <ExclusionEncodings>UTF-8</ExclusionEncodings>
        <ExclusionEncodings>EUC-JP</ExclusionEncodings>
        <ExclusionEncodings>ISO-8859-1</ExclusionEncodings>
        <FileExclusions>
          <Glob/>
          <Expression/>
        </FileExclusions>
        <MountExclusions>
          <DeviceExpression/>
          <DeviceGlob/>
          <MountpointExpression/>
        </MountExclusions>
        <ThreatDetection>
          <U32>
            <EnableAutoStop>0</EnableAutoStop>
            <ExecFileDisinfection>1</ExecFileDisinfection>
            <Xml>0</Xml>
            <SXLLiveProtection>0</SXLLiveProtection>
          </U32>
          <U16/>
          <STR/>
          <VirusDataDir>./lib/sav</VirusDataDir>
          <IdeDir>./lib/sav</IdeDir>
          <UseSharedMemory>false</UseSharedMemory>
          <SXL>
            <ServerList>00010203</ServerList>
            <TopLevelDomain>nix.sophosxl.net</TopLevelDomain>
          </SXL>
        </ThreatDetection>
      </Scanner>
      <Talpa>
        <intercept-filters>
          <Cache>
            <fstypes>ext3</fstypes>
            <fstypes>ext4</fstypes>
            <fstypes>ext2</fstypes>
            <fstypes>tmpfs</fstypes>
            <fstypes>devtmpfs</fstypes>
            <fstypes>iso9660</fstypes>
            <fstypes>udf</fstypes>
            <fstypes>xfs</fstypes>
            <fstypes>reiserfs</fstypes>
            <fstypes>jfs</fstypes>
            <fstypes>vfat</fstypes>
            <fstypes>msdos</fstypes>
            <fstypes>ntfs</fstypes>
            <fstypes>hfs</fstypes>
            <fstypes>minix</fstypes>
            <fstypes>ramfs</fstypes>
            <fstypes>romfs</fstypes>
            <fstypes>ufs</fstypes>
            <fstypes>umsdos</fstypes>
            <fstypes>xenix</fstypes>
            <fstypes>cramfs</fstypes>
            <status>enable</status>
          </Cache>
          <DebugSyslog>
            <status>disable</status>
          </DebugSyslog>
          <FilesystemExclusionProcessor>
            <paths/>
            <fstypes/>
          </FilesystemExclusionProcessor>
          <FilesystemInclusionProcessor>
            <status>false</status>
            <include-path>/</include-path>
          </FilesystemInclusionProcessor>
          <VettingController>
            <timeout-ms>10000</timeout-ms>
            <fs-timeout-ms>60000</fs-timeout-ms>
            <timeout-deny>true</timeout-deny>
            <xsmartsched-fix>true</xsmartsched-fix>
            <interruptible>false</interruptible>
          </VettingController>
        </intercept-filters>
      </Talpa>
      <Fanotify>
        <ExcludeFilesystems/>
      </Fanotify>
      <PreferFanotify>false</PreferFanotify>
      <DisableFanotify>true</DisableFanotify>
    </OnAccess>
    <Notification>
      <debug>False</debug>
      <QueueLimit>50</QueueLimit>
      <Notifiers>
        <Log>
          <Status>True</Status>
          <Location>./log</Location>
          <Prefix>savd</Prefix>
          <MaxSizeMiB>100</MaxSizeMiB>
          <ErrorCategory>log.error</ErrorCategory>
          <ThreatCategory>log.threat</ThreatCategory>
        </Log>
        <Syslog>
          <Status>True</Status>
          <Facility>DAEMON</Facility>
        </Syslog>
        <UI>
          <Status>enabled</Status>
          <ttynotification>True</ttynotification>
          <popupNotification>True</popupNotification>
          <Message>
            <ContactMessage/>
          </Message>
        </UI>
        <Email>
          <Status>enabled</Status>
          <Server>localhost:25</Server>
          <SendThreatEmail>true</SendThreatEmail>
          <SendScanErrorEmail>true</SendScanErrorEmail>
          <SendErrorEmail>true</SendErrorEmail>
          <SendLogEmailLevel>FATAL</SendLogEmailLevel>
          <SendDemandSummaryAlways>false</SendDemandSummaryAlways>
          <SendDemandSummaryIfThreat>true</SendDemandSummaryIfThreat>
          <Message>
            <ThreatMessage/>
            <ScanErrorMessage/>
            <LogMessage/>
          </Message>
          <EmailLanguage>English</EmailLanguage>
          <AlwaysSend>
            <MsgID>USING_BACKUP_CONFIGURATION</MsgID>
            <MsgID>ALL_UPDATE_SOURCES_FAILED</MsgID>
            <MsgID>RESPAWN-LIMIT</MsgID>
            <MsgID>VIRUS-DATA-OLD</MsgID>
            <MsgID>TALPA-FAILURE</MsgID>
            <MsgID>TALPA-COMPILED</MsgID>
          </AlwaysSend>
          <Recipient>
            <To>root@localhost</To>
          </Recipient>
          <Log>true</Log>
        </Email>
      </Notifiers>
    </Notification>
    <OnDemand>
      <LogStartStop>true</LogStartStop>
      <LogDetails>true</LogDetails>
    </OnDemand>
    <Core/>
    <WebUI>
      <HttpPort>8081</HttpPort>
      <Username>admin</Username>
      <Password/>
    </WebUI>
    <CID>
      <SophosUpdateLocation locked="true">sdds:SOPHOS</SophosUpdateLocation>
      <NotifyOnUpdate>false</NotifyOnUpdate>
      <NotifyOnCheck>false</NotifyOnCheck>
    </CID>
    <Update>
      <EnableAutoUpdating>true</EnableAutoUpdating>
      <Primary>
        <Policy>recommended</Policy>
        <UseHttps>true</UseHttps>
      </Primary>
      <Secondary>
        <UseHttps>true</UseHttps>
      </Secondary>
      <UpdateHttpsAllowDowngradeToHttp>true</UpdateHttpsAllowDowngradeToHttp>
    </Update>
    <LogPrimaryUpdateError>true</LogPrimaryUpdateError>
    <DetectionFeedback>
      <MaxQueueSize>8192</MaxQueueSize>
      <LookupDomain>samples.sophosxl.net</LookupDomain>
      <UploadURL>samples.sophosxl.net</UploadURL>
      <UploadFiles>false</UploadFiles>
      <UploadTimeout>120</UploadTimeout>
    </DetectionFeedback>
  </Sophos>
  <Corporate/>
  <ConsoleAV>
    <OnAccess>
      <EnableOnStart>1</EnableOnStart>
      <Scanner>
        <ThreatDetection>
          <U32>
            <FullSweep>0</FullSweep>
            <SfxArchives>0</SfxArchives>
            <ZipDecompression>0</ZipDecompression>
            <ArjDecompression>0</ArjDecompression>
            <RarDecompression>0</RarDecompression>
            <UueDecompression>0</UueDecompression>
            <GZipDecompression>0</GZipDecompression>
            <Deflate>0</Deflate>
            <CmzDecompression>0</CmzDecompression>
            <MSCabinet>0</MSCabinet>
            <ISCabinet>0</ISCabinet>
            <LZMAAlone>0</LZMAAlone>
            <Brotli>0</Brotli>
            <TarDecompression>0</TarDecompression>
            <Lha>0</Lha>
            <MSCompress>0</MSCompress>
            <HqxDecompression>0</HqxDecompression>
            <MbinDecompression>0</MbinDecompression>
            <AppleSingle>0</AppleSingle>
            <Bzip2>0</Bzip2>
            <Sis>0</Sis>
            <Szip>0</Szip>
            <Xar>0</Xar>
            <Egg>0</Egg>
            <Alz>0</Alz>
            <CustomExtract>0</CustomExtract>
            <UnixArchive>0</UnixArchive>
            <Rpm>0</Rpm>
            <SXLLiveProtection>1</SXLLiveProtection>
          </U32>
        </ThreatDetection>
        <AllowIfBootSectorThreat>0</AllowIfBootSectorThreat>
        <FileExclusions>
          <Glob>/tmp/clamav*</Glob>
          <Glob>/tmp/odeiavir*</Glob>
          <Glob>/var/www/vhosts/system/*/logs/*log*</Glob>
          <Glob>/var/www/vhosts/system/*/statistics/logs/*log*</Glob>
          <Glob>/var/www/vhosts/*/logs/*_log*</Glob>
          <Expression/>
        </FileExclusions>
        <AutomaticAction/>
      </Scanner>
      <Talpa>
        <intercept-filters>
          <FilesystemExclusionProcessor>
            <paths>/boot/efi/</paths>
            <paths>/dev/shm/</paths>
            <paths>/opt/app/oracle/</paths>
            <paths>/opt/oracle/</paths>
            <paths>/opt/simpana/</paths>
            <paths>/oratmp/</paths>
            <paths>/run/</paths>
            <paths>/tmp/hsperfdata_oracle/</paths>
            <paths>/u01/app/</paths>
            <paths>/u02/oradata/</paths>
            <paths>/u03/oradata/</paths>
            <paths>/usr/local/pgsql/data/</paths>
            <paths>/usr/local/psa/</paths>
            <paths>/var/drweb/</paths>
            <paths>/var/hsphere/</paths>
            <paths>/var/lib/lxcfs/</paths>
            <paths>/var/lib/mysql/</paths>
            <paths>/var/lib/mysqlbackup/</paths>
            <paths>/var/lib/mysqllogs/</paths>
            <paths>/var/lib/mysqltmp/</paths>
            <paths>/var/lib/pgsql/</paths>
            <paths>/var/lock/</paths>
            <paths>/var/log/</paths>
            <paths>/var/qmail/</paths>
            <paths>/var/run/</paths>
            <paths>/var/spool/</paths>
            <paths>/var/tmp/.oracle/</paths>
            <fstypes append="true"/>
            <status>1</status>
          </FilesystemExclusionProcessor>
        </intercept-filters>
      </Talpa>
      <Quarantine>1</Quarantine>
      <TakeActionOnClose>1</TakeActionOnClose>
      <WindowsAllExtensions>0</WindowsAllExtensions>
      <WindowsNoExtension>1</WindowsNoExtension>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>AVHD</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>AVHDX</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>BAK</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>CHK</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>EDB</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>FRM</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>FWD</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>GSC</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>GSE</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>LDF</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>LOG</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>MBX</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>MDF</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>MYD</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>MYI</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>NDF</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>SDS</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>SMD</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>TRN</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>UND</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>UNF</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>UNH</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>UNI</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>UNQ</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>UNS</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>VAC</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>VHD</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>VHDX</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>VMDX</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>VSV</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionExclusions>WCI</WindowsExtensionExclusions>
      <WindowsExtensionInclusions/>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Clusterstorage\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Imail\Imail\Spool\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files (x86)\Urchin\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\
</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\CommVault Systems\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\CommVault\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\Dell\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\Double-Take Software\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\DoubleTake\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\Ipswitch\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\LogMeIn\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\MegaRAID\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Monitoring Agent\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>
C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2\Server\
</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\MxUptime\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\Operations Manager\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\Parallels\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>
C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager 2007\
</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\Urchin\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\rs-pkgs\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\SmarterMail\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\System Volume Information\DFSR\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Sysvol\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\
</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\
</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Config\
</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\
</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Windows\NTDS\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Datastore\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Windows\Sysvol\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Windows\Syswow64\LogFiles\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Windows\Temp\Gthrsvc\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Winnt\Temp\Gthrsvc\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>HealthService.exe</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>ManagementService.exe</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>Microsoft.Mom.ConfigServiceHost.exe</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>Microsoft.Mom.Sdk.Service.exe</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>MonitoringHost.exe</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>MSMDSrv.exe</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>pagefile.sys</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>ReportingServicesService.exe</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>SQLServr.exe</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>vmh.exe</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>vmms.exe</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>vmwp.exe</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExclusion>C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center\</WindowsExclusion>
      <WindowsExcludeRemoteFiles>0</WindowsExcludeRemoteFiles>
      <WindowsFileRead>0</WindowsFileRead>
      <WindowsFileWrite>1</WindowsFileWrite>
      <WindowsFileRename>1</WindowsFileRename>
    </OnAccess>
    <ContinuousScan>
      <WindowsKernelMemoryScan>1</WindowsKernelMemoryScan>
    </ContinuousScan>
    <OnDemand>
      <NamedScanList>SEC:FullSystemScan</NamedScanList>
      <NamedScans>
        <RichElement element_name="SEC:FullSystemScan" encoding="quoted printable">
scanHardDrives=3Dtrue=0AscanOpticalDrives=3Dtrue=0AscanNetworkFilesystems=3Dfalse=0AscanRemovableDevices=3Dtrue=0AscanWindowsKernelMemory=3Dfalse=0AscanLevel=3Dnormal=0AscanArchives=3Dfalse=0Adisinfect=3Dfalse=0AthreatAction=3Ddonothing=0Aexclude=3D/boot/efi/=0Aexclude=3D/dev/shm/=0Aexclude=3D/opt/app/oracle/=0Aexclude=3D/opt/shm/=0Aexclude=3D/opt/simpana/=0Aexclude=3D/oratemp/=0Aexclude=3D/run/=0Aexclude=3D/tmp/clamav*=0Aexclude=3D/tmp/hsperfdata_oracle/=0Aexclude=3D/tmp/odeiavir*=0Aexclude=3D/u01/app/=0Aexclude=3D/u02/oradata/=0Aexclude=3D/u03/oradata/=0Aexclude=3D/usr/local/pgsql/data/=0Aexclude=3D/usr/local/psa/=0Aexclude=3D/var/drweb/=0Aexclude=3D/var/hsphere/=0Aexclude=3D/var/lib/mysql/=0Aexclude=3D/var/lib/mysqlbackup/=0Aexclude=3D/var/lib/mysqllogs/=0Aexclude=3D/var/lib/mysqltmp/=0Aexclude=3D/var/lib/pgsql/=0Aexclude=3D/var/lock/=0Aexclude=3D/var/log/=0Aexclude=3D/var/named/chroot/=0Aexclude=3D/var/qmail/=0Aexclude=3D/var/run/=0Aexclude=3D/var/spool/=0Aexclude=3D/var/tmp/.oracle/=0Aexclude=3D/var/www/vhosts/system/*/logs/*log*=0Aexclude=3D/var/www/vhosts/system/*/statistics/logs/*log*=0Aexclude=3D/var/www/vhosts/*/logs/*_log*=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Clusterstorage\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Imail\Imail\Spool\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files (x86)\Urchin\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\CommVault Systems\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\CommVault\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\Dell\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\Double-Take Software\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\DoubleTake\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\Ipswitch\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\LogMeIn\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\MegaRAID\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\Microsoft Monitoring Agent\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2\Server\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\MxUptime\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\Operations Manager\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\Parallels\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager 2007\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Program Files\Urchin\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\rs-pkgs\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\SmarterMail\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\System Volume Information\DFSR\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Sysvol\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Config\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\NTDS\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Datastore\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\Sysvol\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\Syswow64\LogFiles\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Windows\Temp\Gthrsvc\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DC:\Winnt\Temp\Gthrsvc\=0AwindowsExclusion=3DHealthService.exe=0AwindowsExclusion=3DManagementService.exe=0AwindowsExclusion=3DMicrosoft.Mom.ConfigServiceHost.exe=0AwindowsExclusion=3DMicrosoft.Mom.Sdk.Service.exe=0AwindowsExclusion=3DMonitoringHost.exe=0AwindowsExclusion=3DMSMDSrv.exe=0AwindowsExclusion=3Dpagefile.sys=0AwindowsExclusion=3DReportingServicesService.exe=0AwindowsExclusion=3DSQLServr.exe=0AwindowsExclusion=3Dvmh.exe=0AwindowsExclusion=3Dvmms.exe=0AwindowsExclusion=3Dvmwp.exe=0AscanAll=3Dfalse=0AscanFilesWithoutExtension=3Dtrue=0AexcludeExtension=3DAVHD=0AexcludeExtension=3DAVHDX=0AexcludeExtension=3DBAK=0AexcludeExtension=3DCHK=0AexcludeExtension=3DFRM=0AexcludeExtension=3DFWD=0AexcludeExtension=3DGSC=0AexcludeExtension=3DGSE=0AexcludeExtension=3DLDF=0AexcludeExtension=3DLOG=0AexcludeExtension=3DMBX=0AexcludeExtension=3DMDF=0AexcludeExtension=3DMYD=0AexcludeExtension=3DMYI=0AexcludeExtension=3DNDF=0AexcludeExtension=3DSDS=0AexcludeExtension=3DSMD=0AexcludeExtension=3DTRN=0AexcludeExtension=3DUND=0AexcludeExtension=3DUNF=0AexcludeExtension=3DUNH=0AexcludeExtension=3DUNI=0AexcludeExtension=3DUNQ=0AexcludeExtension=3DUNS=0AexcludeExtension=3DVAC=0AexcludeExtension=3DVHD=0AexcludeExtension=3DVHDX=0AexcludeExtension=3DVMDX=0AexcludeExtension=3DVSV=0AexcludeExtension=3DWCI=0AexcludeExtension=3DEDB=0AdropFileCache=3Dtrue=0A
</RichElement>
      </NamedScans>
    </OnDemand>
    <Notification>
      <Notifiers>
        <UI>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <popupNotification>1</popupNotification>
          <ttynotification>1</ttynotification>
          <Message>
            <ContactMessage/>
          </Message>
        </UI>
        <Email>
          <EmailLanguage>english</EmailLanguage>
          <SendScanErrorEmail>0</SendScanErrorEmail>
          <Server/>
          <Sender/>
          <ReplyTo/>
          <SendThreatEmail>0</SendThreatEmail>
          <Status>0</Status>
          <Message>
            <ThreatMessage/>
            <ScanErrorMessage/>
            <LogMessage/>
          </Message>
          <Recipient>
            <To/>
          </Recipient>
        </Email>
      </Notifiers>
    </Notification>
    <DetectionFeedback>
      <UploadFiles>1</UploadFiles>
    </DetectionFeedback>
  </ConsoleAV>
  <ConsoleUpdate>
    <Update>
      <Primary>
        <Source locked="true">
http://89.234.28.42/SophosUpdate/CIDs/S001/savlinux
</Source>
        <Cache>/opt/sophos-av/update/cache/Primary</Cache>
        <Username locked="true"/>
        <Password locked="true"/>
        <Proxy>
          <Address locked="true"/>
          <Username locked="true"/>
          <Password locked="true"/>
        </Proxy>
      </Primary>
      <Secondary>
        <Source locked="true">
http://89.234.28.37/SophosUpdate/CIDs/S001/savlinux
</Source>
        <Cache>/opt/sophos-av/update/cache/Secondary</Cache>
        <Username locked="true"/>
        <Password locked="true"/>
        <Proxy>
          <Address locked="true"/>
          <Username locked="true"/>
          <Password locked="true"/>
        </Proxy>
      </Secondary>
      <PeriodMinutes locked="true">240</PeriodMinutes>
      <EnableAutoUpdating locked="true">true</EnableAutoUpdating>
    </Update>
  </ConsoleUpdate>
  <Machine/>
  <User>
    <OnAccess>
      <Scanner>
        <ThreatDetection>
          <U32/>
        </ThreatDetection>
      </Scanner>
      <Talpa>
        <intercept-filters>
          <VettingController>
            <ops>-open</ops>
          </VettingController>
        </intercept-filters>
      </Talpa>
      <DisableFanotify>0</DisableFanotify>
      <PreferFanotify>1</PreferFanotify>
    </OnAccess>
    <DetectionFeedback/>
    <Update>
      <PeriodMinutes>11</PeriodMinutes>
      <Primary>
        <Source>
http://89.234.28.37/SophosUpdate/CIDs/S001/savlinux/
</Source>
      </Primary>
    </Update>
    <WebUI>
      <Password>***</Password>
    </WebUI>
  </User>
</SophosAntiVirus>
```

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem is that scanning on open is turned off:

```
      <VettingController>
        <ops>-open</ops>
      </VettingController>
```

That will be why the final accesses are allowed. (Copying the file, and accessing it through the browser).

That means there is only scanning on-close-after-write. I'm not sure why the upload was allowed. Maybe Wordpress wrote the file to one of the excluded locations then moved it?

Comment: Thank you, I've removed that config and retried, no luck though - see my edit above.